# Make Firefox open new windows as new tabs BUT open JavaScript popups as popups

Tags: firefox, popups, browser-tabs

It's happened again: Firefox started letting new windows open as new windows and not capturing them in tabs instead. So of course JavaScript popups work properly, but my tab preferences are not correct. Open those new pages in tabs, *always*, please.

This happened before. And I [fixed it with an about:config hack](http://abrokenmold.blogspot.com/2009/05/fixed-firefox-not-opening-requested.html).

> > if you open about:config in your address bar, you can change the
> >     setting manually.
> >     Change: browser.link.open_newwindow
> >     Mine was set to 3, which told the popups to always open in a new tab.
>
> Niceness. It's a pretty easy fix. Set
>   it to 2. I just wonder what changed it
>   to 3. Wasn't me.

So I set it to 3 again. And now links always open in a new tab. Good. And now Javascript popups come up in a new tab. **Bad**. This is extremely annoying. This shouldn't happen. Popups that are supposed to be popups should *pop up*! Anybody have a solution (and an explanation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting [browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction) to 2 might fix the problem:

> **2 :** Divert all links according to
>   browser.link.open_newwindow, unless
>   the new window specifies how it should
>   be displayed.

Comment: Yes. That did it. Thank you!!!!!! Now what screwed it up in the first place?

Comment: @Nathaniel: No idea at all.

Comment: I don't really know either. I recently installed a couple tab related add-ons (and uninstalled them), but I don't remember if this started before or after. Thanks for the answer.